# How to clear pending analysis in Cuckoo sandbox platform

Tags: python, virtual-machine, antivirus, malware-detection, cuckoo

I am testing malware detection on guest VM using Cuckoo sandbox platform. To speed up the analysis, I want to remove pending analysis but keep completed analysis.

Cuckoo have --clean option but it will clean all tasks and samples. Can you think of a way to only remove pending analysis?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by deleting entries from the mysql database for pending analysis.